# Another question on representation of even integers from some point after , in the form $a^x+b^y$

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist positive integers $x,y$ ; $x>1$ and $k  \in \mathbb N$ , such that for every even integer $n \ge k$ , $ \exists a,b \in \mathbb N$ such that   $n=a^x+b^y$ , where $a>b>1$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ ?

Comment: are you allowing $y=1?$

Comment: @Will, even allowing $y=1$, the condition $a>b>1$ would seem to make it impossible to represent, say, 98 as $a^2+b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks. This is easy by density arguments when $x,y \geq 2.$

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Thanks to Gerry Myerson: if $y=1$ and $x \geq 2,$ take large $M.$ We will not be able to represent any $n$ satisfying
$$  M^x + M \; \leq \; n \;  \leq \;  (M+1)^x - 1 $$ 
as $a^x + b$ **with $a > b > 0.$** Try this with $x=2$ and $M=9,$ as Gerry suggests.

Saturday: In the output below, I allowed $a > b \geq 0$ in $a^2 + b.$

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
      a^2  + b      a        b   
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
           1        1        0
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
           4        2        0
           5        2        1
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
           9        3        0
          10        3        1
          11        3        2
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          16        4        0
          17        4        1
          18        4        2
          19        4        3
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          25        5        0
          26        5        1
          27        5        2
          28        5        3
          29        5        4
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          36        6        0
          37        6        1
          38        6        2
          39        6        3
          40        6        4
          41        6        5
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          49        7        0
          50        7        1
          51        7        2
          52        7        3
          53        7        4
          54        7        5
          55        7        6
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          64        8        0
          65        8        1
          66        8        2
          67        8        3
          68        8        4
          69        8        5
          70        8        6
          71        8        7
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
          81        9        0
          82        9        1
          83        9        2
          84        9        3
          85        9        4
          86        9        5
          87        9        6
          88        9        7
          89        9        8
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
         100       10        0
         101       10        1
         102       10        2
         103       10        3
         104       10        4
         105       10        5
         106       10        6
         107       10        7
         108       10        8
         109       10        9
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
      a^2  + b      a        b   
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

ORIGINAL: If both $x,y \geq 2,$ then the count of numbers up to some large positive $N$ is, eventually, $o(N).$

When $$  \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} < 1, $$ 
the count of represented numbers is, at most, 
$$  N^{ \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \right)} $$ times a constant.

When $x=y=2,$ the count is asymptotically
$$  \frac{0.7642 N}{\sqrt {\log N} \; }   $$

For $  \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} < 1, $ the point is that the number of integer lattice points in a set in the plane is well approximated by the area of the region, as long as the region is convex. This applies to the circle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem#Bounds_on_a_solution_and_conjecture and more complicated regions (and in three dimensions, using volume) http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511470929  Here we have the set
$$ x,y \geq 0, x^m + y^n \leq W  $$
for some large positive $W.$ the area is equal to $$  W^{ \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n} \right)} $$ times a constant, where the constant is the area of
 $$ x,y \geq 0, x^m + y^n \leq 1.  $$ All that happens is that $x=1$ is stretched out to $x = W^{1/m},$ and $y=1$ is stretched out to $y = W^{1/n}.$ This kind of area calculation is common to linear algebra and multivariable calculus, there is a liner mapping taking the region for $1$ to the region for $W,$ we have found the determinant of the Jacobian.

The result on the sum of two squares is more subtle, and in the last few pages of http://store.doverpublications.com/0486425398.html

Comment: Yes , I am allowing $y=1$ . Could you please elaborate why $n$ in $[M^x+M , M^{x+1}-1]$ cannot be represented as $a^x+b$ ? and could you please give the details of the counting formulas for other examples ?

Comment: @ Will Jagy : Could you please explain that impossibility of representing any numbers as $a^x+b$ in $[M^x+M , (M+1)^x -1]$ ; I haven't understood it yet

Comment: @SaunDev, it is just inequalities; I put in computer output for $a^2 + b$ with $a > b \geq 0.$ This gives all the numbers from $a^2$ up to $a^2 + a-1.$ However, $(a+1)^2 = a^2 + 2 a + 1,$ and you get larger numbers still by adding any $b.$ So we have no way to represent all those numbers from, say, $a^2 + a $ to $a^2 + 2a,$ which is $(a+1)^2 - 1.$ The gaps are even bigger if we look at output for $a^3 + b;$ I suggest you do that. I also put in some references. What is your background?